# Обработка результатов поиска в angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Здравствуйте!
Есть такая конструкция

`<tr ng-repeat="task in tasksArray | filter: search">`

При поиске если нет элемента в массиве надо вывести, какое-то сообщение типа 'not found'. Как это можно сделать?

P.S Заранее прошу прощения за свою некомпетентность, т.к я новичок.

Answer (score 0):

можно так:

```
<div ng-if="(task in tasksArray | filter: search).length == 0">not found</div>
```

только это не в табличку а до неё или после, можно вместо.

Comment: Написал так                                                                                         `<div>
    <table class="table">
      ...
        <tr ng-repeat="task in tasksArray | filter: search"</tr>
    </table>
</div>
<div ng-if="(task in tasksArray | filter: search).length == 0">not found</div>`.
Выдает ошибку    `Syntax Error: Token 'in' is unexpected, expecting [)] at column 7 of the expression [(task in tasksArray | filter: search).length == 0] starting at [in tasksArray | filter: search).length == 0].`

Comment: @r.mcreal тут не нужен `in` совсем, правильно будет `<div ng-if="(tasksArray | filter: search).length == 0">not found</div>`

Comment: @Igor Golovin Вы гений. Спасибо большое!